# Rotation formalisms in three dimensions

Tags: geometry, transformation, 3d, rotations

I'm little bit confused. The Rotations are described by various means
Direction Cosines Matrix (DCM);
Euler Angles;
Euler Axis/Angle;
Quaternion.

What is the difference between them. How I can convert the orientation from one representation to another.

My question here: I have a the orientation of an object in terms of direction cosine vector. 
See the following figure; [direction cosine - unit vector](http://akita-nct.jp/yamamoto/lecture/2006/p1/1st/html/img94.png)

Note that the vector `r` makes angle alpha with x-axis, beta with y-axis and gamma with z-axis.

I want to represent this orientation in tearms of Quaternion. Is that possible? if yes, How we can represent this angles in terms of Quaternion (Axis,Angle,Matrix).

Thanks for the Help!.

Comment: little ad hoc [ http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177064/quaternions-and-rotations ]

Comment: I'm not a mathematician. I could not understand the discussions in the link above! Could you provide more explanation please.

Comment: I know you're not a mathematician but maybe this link will help. [Conversion between quaternions and Euler Angles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles)

Answer (score 0):

The [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions) provides all the conversions you could ask for. Specifically you may want [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions#Euler_axis.2Fangle_.E2.86.94_quaternion) section.

The formalism (or system) you eventually choose depends on your application. In theory, using any or all of those systems is possible.

Rather than rehashing *all* of that stuff here, you might want to spend time to pick out the one that sounds right to you, and then ask some targeted question about it.

---

**Update:** The request was clarified to changing from a direction cosine to a quaternion. The quaternion needs two pieces of data: the components of the unit vector $u$ on the axis of rotation, and the angle of rotation $\theta$ (measured in a right-hand manner in the plane normal to $u$.)

The three angles in your picture will give you $u$, and I assume you want to specify $\theta$ later. Finding the components of the vector in the picture is easy: the projections onto the axes are just $\cos(\alpha)$, $\cos(\beta)$, and $\cos(\gamma)$, so $u=i\cos(\alpha)+j\cos(\beta)+k\cos(\gamma)$.

In the scheme of quaternion rotations, the matching quaternion is $q=\cos(\theta/2)+u\sin(\theta/2)$.

Comment: I've been trying to solve a problem. I'm surprised I haven't been able to find anything really useful on the net so far.
my question simply; how it possible to **convert the Direction Vector to Quaternion (Axis,Angle,Matrix)**. I have a direction vector as shown in the 
figure; [Fig.1](http://akita-nct.jp/yamamoto/lecture/2006/p1/1st/html/img94.png) I want to generate Quaternion.

Comment: @user11819 I do not understand what you mean when you type (Axis, Angle, Matrix) next to quaternion. I can help you convert a direction cosine to a quaternion. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm looking for; Convert a direction cosine to a quaternion. 
the only information I have is the alpha,beta and gamma angles that the normal vector makes with the base axis: x-axis, y-axis and z-axis respectively. 
As given in this figure [Fig.1](http://akita-nct.jp/yamamoto/lecture/2006/p1/1st/html/img94.png).

Comment: @user11819 ok: I added an update for that.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I just need to clarify something here. 
The angle of rotation θ could be calculated from the figure that I attached? or the information I have is not enough to calculate θ? Because I already knew that I need an axis and angle to find the Quaternion; but my problem is how to extract the axis (u) and the angle (θ) from the figure above!. you helped me to define the axis (u); but I'm still confused about calculating the angle (θ)!

Comment: @user11819 It seems to me that the data in your picture is only enough to establish a *direction* but not enough to establish an angle of rotation. I think that a $3$-d rotation requires a minimum of four real parameters.